# How to fix recycling of list view in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom list view having multiple rows. Each row have a layout as header with some name on it. i am setting this layout visibility to GONE when the name on the layout is same for the next row. else setting visibility to VISIBLE. for the first time when list view loads its working fine.But problem comes when i scroll the list view, VISIBILITY changes to every scroll.

GetView Method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.product_item_details, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.imgBtnLv=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnLv);
        viewHolder.categBar=(LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categBar);
        viewHolder.tvTitleCateg=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleCateg);
        viewHolder.item_detail_layout=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail_layout);
        viewHolder.titlebar2=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titlebar2);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        if (position == 0) {
        ProductsActivity p=(ProductsActivity) mContext;
         System.out.println("edit text value >>>-= "+p.edtSearch.getText().toString()); 
         String searchText=p.edtSearch.getText().toString();
         if(searchText==null||searchText.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
             viewHolder.titlebar2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e9ecfa"));
         }else{

             viewHolder.titlebar2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

          }

    } else {
        // set color back to original color
        viewHolder.titlebar2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e9ecfa"));
    }





    viewHolder.tvTitleCateg.setText(creditItems.get(position).getBrand());
    viewHolder.tvPrice.setText(creditItems.get(position).getPrice());
    viewHolder.tvQuantity.setText(creditItems.get(position).getInstock());
    viewHolder.tvDiscount.setText(creditItems.get(position).getDiscount());

    String currBrand =  creditItems.get(position).getBrand();

    viewHolder.categBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    notifyDataSetChanged();         

    if(prevBrand.equalsIgnoreCase(currBrand)){

        viewHolder.categBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        System.out.println("view Gone "+position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        viewHolder.categBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    System.out.println("view Visible"+position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    prevBrand= currBrand;
```

When i scroll the list view,in log cat the messages are

```
6-04 16:10:44.090: I/System.out(12883): view Visible0
06-04 16:10:44.113: I/System.out(12883): view Visible1
06-04 16:10:44.129: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 2
06-04 16:10:44.145: I/System.out(12883): view Visible3
06-04 16:10:44.160: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 4
06-04 16:10:44.176: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 5
06-04 16:10:44.192: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 6
06-04 16:10:44.207: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 7
06-04 16:10:44.223: I/System.out(12883): view Visible8
06-04 16:10:44.238: I/System.out(12883): view Visible9
06-04 16:10:52.270: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 10
06-04 16:10:52.285: I/System.out(12883): edit text value >>>-= 
06-04 16:10:52.285: I/System.out(12883): view Visible0
06-04 16:10:52.293: I/System.out(12883): view Visible1
06-04 16:10:52.301: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 2
06-04 16:10:52.301: I/System.out(12883): view Visible3
06-04 16:10:52.309: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 4
06-04 16:10:52.309: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 5
06-04 16:10:52.317: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 6
06-04 16:10:52.317: I/System.out(12883): view Gone 7
06-04 16:10:52.324: I/System.out(12883): view Visible8
06-04 16:10:52.465: I/System.out(12883): view Visible1
06-04 16:10:52.973: I/System.out(12883): view Visible0
06-04 16:10:52.981: I/System.out(12883): view Visible2
06-04 16:10:52.988: I/System.out(12883): view Visible3
```

how to fix the visibility or how to fix this problem.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `prevBrand` is some kind of global variable. For sure Android should not create views in sequential order. If you scroll to the top the views for higher position will be created sooner.
So you need to get prevBrand something like this

```
String prevBrand =  position > 0? creditItems.get(position - 1).getBrand(): "";
```

Also please don't call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the getView method